# Two websites in same cpanel. .htaccess file for the main website is restricting the secondary website and I am not sure how

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

This is my first time posting on here so please excuse any informalities and feel free to suggest ways I can ask my question more clearly.

For economic reasons, my boss wants to have two websites contained in the same hosting plan, and thus the same cpanel. **Website 1** is located in public_html and **Website 2** is located in a stand-alone directory inside the same folder.

Website 1 runs on Magento, and therefore seems to have a very specific nomenclature within the .htaccess file. Something about that file is causing Website 2 to receive a 403 Forbidden Error everytime it tries to load:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

renaming the .htaccess file to .htaccess.old solves the issue and lets Website 2 load, but introduces issues with the paths and links on Website 1, naturally.

If anybody is willing to help, I would be happy to put specifics of the code inside the .htaccess file in the comments for dissection. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: In response to a kind comment, here is the entirety of the .htaccess file:

```
enter code here
#RewriteEngine On 
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?adventurelights\.com
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.adventurelights.com/$1 [R,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guardianlights\.com$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.guardianlights\.com$

#RewriteRule ^products\/hunting$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/hunting" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/boating$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/boating" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/pets$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/pets" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/water-sports$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/water-sports" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/camping-mountaineering$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/camping" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/running$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/running" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/biking$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/biking" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/guardian-trident-expedition-light$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/guardian-trident-expedition-light" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/guardian-running-light$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/guardian-trident-running-light" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/guardian-trident-bike-light$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/guardian-trident-bike-light" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/guardian-trident-dog-light$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/guardian-trident-dog-light" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/vip-expedition$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/vip-expedition" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/vip-emergency-distress$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/vip-emergency-distress" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/vip-expedition-pro$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/vip-expedition-pro" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/guardian-expedition$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/guardian-expedition" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/guardian-dog-collar-light$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/guardian-dog-collar-light" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/guardian-small-pets$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/guardian-for-small-pets" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/guardian-hunting-dog-light$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/guardian-hunting-dog-light" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/guardian-running-light$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/guardian-running-light" [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^products\/guardian-tag-it$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/guardian-tag-it" [R=301,L]
#0RewriteRule ^products\/vip$ "http:\/\/guardianlights.com\/vip-expedition" [R=301,L]

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
##    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

  ############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Comment: In Cpanel you can set the root for website 2 to any path you’d like. Move website out of public_html to public_html_two for example.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update your question (not in the comments) to include your entire `.htaccess` file, so we can see what maybe happening. There's an order of operations that may not be translated if it is partially complete. How do you navigate to **Website 2** in the browser (subdirectory of Website 1, domain, or subdomain)? This will affect how the rules apply in the `htaccess` file and virtual server configurations.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! Edited the OP with the htaccess code.

user9189147: thank you I will look into that option! 

@fyrye Root for Website 1 is Public_HTML, which also contains the root directory for Website 2 (a folder called quantummarine.com). Website 2 is a standalone domain. 

Many thanks to both of you!